# Example for Backbone-relational with Marionette views

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-relational

I've just recently stared using backbone.js and since i have a rather large data-structure,
i am using backbone-relational in order to keep it as lean and as fast as possible.

Now i would like to use marionette views, but i've been struggling to get the rendering
for collections of collections and childviews and all that to work nicely.

So i was wondering if anyone has a example that would use backbone-relational AND marionette at the same time, that shows how to deal with the views correctly.

any help is greatly appreciated

C

Comment: In my experience backbone relational is anything but lean and fast, especially for larger collections. Just a friendly advice: test and measure if it works for you before committing to it.

Comment: ookay, then i might have been mislead on that. guess i should do some checking on it. thanks.

Comment: YMMV of course, but when the client datasets get large, updates to the relational store tend to get really slow and the event overhead gets measurably large. I haven't used it for a while, but in my tests building `HasMany` relations from a collection with 200 items to one with 500 items froze the browser for seconds.  If you mean you have a large data set on the server, but only plan to bring small bits of it to the client, then this might not be a problem.

Comment: i see. well i want to build it as performant as possible, and since i'm also thinking of scalability i might not go with the relational then, because who knows how much bigger the data is gonna get in a year or two... thanks for you input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marionette has a CompositeView that works best with nested collections.

[Marionette CompositeView documentation](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.compositeview.md)

[Marionette CompositeView Article](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/05/composite-views-tree-structures-tables-and-more/)